# Writing file to GCS using resumable upload url

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm generating resumable upload urls using service key impersonation. However I'm not able to use the url for writing the file.

I'm using a PUT request, but the file isn't being written into the bucket. This is the response I get:

```
curl -X PUT -T "temp.json" "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/temp-bucket/o?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ADPycdt5syFNnE7mhpI7-zDvsSBsAvggbN9OoRO0L3sxxxxxx"
{
  "kind": "storage#object",
  "id": "temp-bucket/temp.json/1653298451710685",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/temp-bucket/o/temp.json",
  "mediaLink": "https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/temp-bucket/o/temp.json?generation=1653298451710685&alt=media",
  "name": "temp.json",
  "bucket": "temp-bucket",
  "generation": "1653298451710685",
  "metageneration": "1",
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "storageClass": "STANDARD",
  "size": "23",
  "md5Hash": "GlEmumKUMqtQEY9mx0+JRQ==",
  "crc32c": "4OdQJg==",
  "etag": "CN2FsNeo9fcCEAE=",
  "timeCreated": "2022-05-23T09:34:11.781Z",
  "updated": "2022-05-23T09:34:11.781Z",
  "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2022-05-23T09:34:11.781Z"
}
```

I'm trying to do it in Python as well, but can't find a way to upload the data when it's not a string.

```
import urllib3
import requests
from google.resumable_media.requests import SimpleUpload
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests as tr_requests
import functions_framework
@functions_framework.http
def main(request):
    config = request.get_json(silent=True)
    UPLOAD_URL = config['UPLOAD_URL']
    upload = SimpleUpload(UPLOAD_URL)
    data = open('temp.json', 'rb').encode('utf-8')
    target_scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes = (target_scopes,))
    transport = tr_requests.AuthorizedSession(credentials)
    content_type = 'application/json'
    response = upload.transmit(transport, data, content_type)
    return response
```

Error :

```
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/resumable_media/_upload.py", line 202, in _prepare_request raise TypeError("`data` must be bytes, received", type(data)) TypeError: ('`data` must be bytes, received', <class '_io.BufferedReader'>)
```

This is confusing, a normal PUT call is supposed to work right?

```
$ curl -i -X PUT --data-binary @temp.json \
> -H "Content-Length: 23" \
> "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/temp-bucket/o?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=adpdodldldldldldldid"
HTTP/2 400
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
referrer-policy: no-referrer
content-length: 1555
date: Mon, 23 May 2022 13:54:52 GMT
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
```

Comment: is `UPLOAD_URL` an url generated with `generate_signed_url` method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do multiple requests to upload a file with the resumable feature ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads)):

- one request to create the resumable session:

```sh
curl -i -X POST --data-binary @METADATA_LOCATION \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Length: INITIAL_REQUEST_LENGTH" \
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=resumable&name=OBJECT_NAME"
```

- one or multiple requests to upload the file:

```sh
curl -i -X PUT --data-binary @OBJECT_LOCATION \
    -H "Content-Length: OBJECT_SIZE" \
    "SESSION_URI"
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not supposed to use OAUTH tokens like that for security purposes which is why I created resumable upload urls using service key impersonation with google functions ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71380482/13639008) is the signed url implementation, resumable upload implementation is also quite similar.

Comment: then you can directly do the second `curl` with your signed url?

Comment: with python SDK, you need to create a [resumable session](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-resumable-media/latest/resumable_media/requests.html#resumable-uploads) to get an `uploadID`. You need it as [query parameter](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#query) for `generate_signed_url`.